# Chrome Extension, trigger click on the icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I searched on Google and StackOverflow, and I was not able to find a solution to my problem (to my greatest surprise).

I'm looking to display the popup, exactly like when the user click on the icon of my extension, but via javascript.

The idea behind it is simple : On a specific page, I inject a button and add an event listener on it ("click"). When the user click on that button, I'd like to display the tooltip, simple as that :)

... but I can not find anything related to it. Any idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the popup is impossible without user interaction. For good reason too, remember that no one likes popups that open themselves. What you can do is inject your popup onto the site the user is at, through a content script.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Also, the Chromium team were working on a sidebar for extensions and apps. Unfortunately, that effort was recently discontinued.

Comment: The "popup" I talk about is the popup of my extensions, the html that appears when you click on any icon. And this content would be displayed when the user click on the button I've injected in the current page.

Comment: Yep, my answer still stands I'm afraid. I've tried to do this myself in the past, and haven't noticed any changes to the Chrome browser action API. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

Comment: Thank you for your answer then :) In the meantime I have found an alternative : instead of showing the tooltip, I removed it and added an event (`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`) that adds html in the `activeTab` (permission). So it's good too :)

Comment: @HaibaraAi The answer is accepted because it answer the question :) The question was how to display the tooltip, and the answer says it's impossible, thus it's an answer. Not the one I was expecting but well ..

Comment: @CyrilN. Your question is "On a specific page, I inject a button and add an event listener on it ("click"). When the user click on that button, I'd like to display the tooltip, simple as that :)", why "it's impossible" is an answer? Sorry I'm a little confused but I just think page action could be better answer..

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, but I need my icon to always be visible, and the documentation says `If you want the extension's icon to always be visible, use a browser action instead.` (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction)

Answer (score 0):

As per your description,

> On a **specific** page, I inject a button and add an event listener on it ("click"). When the user click on that button, I'd like to display the tooltip, simple as that :)

I think what you need is just [chrome.pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), it's similar to browserAction, while represents actions that can be taken on the current page, but aren't applicable to all pages.

Comment: He also specified that `I'm looking to display the popup, exactly like when the user click on the icon of my extension, but via javascript.` and that he wanted to `inject a button` in order to do that, - which still can't be done through the page action API. However I agree that a page action could be more appropriate in this context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But which part can't be done thru page action? User can click on the icon of page action, page action can show popup, is there anything I missed?

Comment: As I understood it, he wants to display the popup `**exactly** like when the user click on the icon of my extension`, and do that using an **injected** button. I assume an injected button can't open the popup of a page action omnibar icon either? So a page action in this case would solve the part about being visible on a specific page, but not the part about button injection (presumably injection onto the active site through a content script). If he is OK with the button-icon being in the omnibar instead then a page action is good.

Comment: I see... So you are assuming he wanted to show the button outside the address bar (browser action) while not inside the address bar (page action).

Comment: Yes, I assumed he wanted to **inject** the button on the current page the user is viewing. Once relieved of that contstraint, page actions are interesting. Given the question, as it stands, I feel the correct answer is still that the Chromium team purposefully required user interaction for extension based popups. No JS click trigger allowed. I'm glad you're providing him with a good alternative though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to [Chrome Extension FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/faq/#faq-open-popups):

> ...popups can only be opened if the user clicks on the corresponding page or browser action. An extension cannot open its popup programmatically.